# How can I handle memory consumption on long loops using Node 6.2.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, bluebird

I have been trying to implement a job that will run through a few million entries in my database to update properties based on values in another collection.

The structure is along the lines of

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

var updateFunc = Promise.coroutine(function* (skip, limit) {
    let objects = yield repository.getDocs({}, skip, limit);
    // perform other actions on objects
});

var loopFunc = Promise.coroutine(function* () {
    const count = yield repository.countDocs({});

    var skip = 0;
    var limit = 10000;
    let runs = Math.ceil(count/limit);

    for (let i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        yield updateFunc(skip, limit);
        skip += limit;
    }
});

Promise.coroutine(function* () {
    var start = new Date().getTime();

    yield loopFunc();

    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var timeTaken = ((end - start) / 1000);
    console.log('finished in %s seconds..', parseFloat(timeTaken).toFixed(2));
    process.exit(0);
})();
```

this consumes memory pretty quickly until it crashes.

If I move the while-true into the main function directly after loopFunc returns then after 30 seconds or so it will release the memory.

I figure that the loopFunc is stopping memory from being released as long as it is running, for the job I require a fairly long running loop.

One thought is to break it into pieces and run each part in a separate child process, but I would like to understand why this is not working.

Everything I have tried has come up unsuccessful.

I thought perhaps it was something in the repository leaking memory but if I just create a huge array in updateFunc and have no reference to anything else it still holds memory.

I also tried forcing garbage collection with --expose-gc on start and global.gc() every X runs in the loop and this also failed to produce any better results.

Any idea what I am missing here?

*** UPDATE ***

I have managed to get the memory slightly under control using process.nextTick instead of a loop.

my new code looks like

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
var kill = false;

var updateFunc = Promise.coroutine(function* (skip, limit, runs, run, count) {
    let objects = yield repository.getDocs({}, skip, limit);
    // perform other actions on objects

    if (run < runs) {
        process.nextTick(Promise.coroutine(function* () {
            yield locator.helper.makePromise(null, 2000, true);
            yield updateFunc(skip+limit, limit, runs, run+1, count);
        }));
    } else {
        kill = true;
    }
});

Promise.coroutine(function* () {
    var start = new Date().getTime();

    var count = yield locator.repository.count(locator.db.absence, {});
    console.log('checking %s companies...', count);

    var skip = 0;
    var limit = 10000;
    let runs = Math.ceil(count/limit);

    yield updateFunc(skip, limit, runs+1, 1, count);

    while(!kill) {
        yield locator.helper.makePromise(null, 5000, true);
    }

    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var timeTaken = ((end - start) / 1000);
    console.log('finished in %s seconds..', parseFloat(timeTaken).toFixed(2));
    process.exit(0);
})();
```

Using nextTick to call the updateFunc seem to allow the GC to do its job which is great. Memory grows quickly and then after it hits about 1 GB, it gets cleaned up and drops.

I need the while loop with the wait so that the updateFunc has time to run to completion, once it hits the max runs I can break out and kill the process.

I am still looking for some ways to improve on it, but I am finally making progress.